# Loosing page style when adding translated page on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, translation, multilingual

i am new with Wordpress and i am trying to update an existing website.

I have an English Front page (Uvodna stran) that looks like this:

[image]

When i click on "+" to add the German translation the new page is correctly created and the new language "DE" appears in the main front page with the other languages.

[image]

[image]

The problem though is that the setting of the main front page (the one in english) is not passed over and the new DE page looks like this:

[image]

So i am wondering what am i doing wrong? How can i keep the same setting and get the page translated?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a cache issue with Elementor.

Within your WordPress dashboard, go to Elementor > Tools > General and click on the button "Regenerate Files & Data". Then press on the "Save Changes" button.